# VenoBox - слишком большой margin-top, margin-bottom

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Сайт на WordPress, при открытии фотографии у .vbox-content слишком большой margin-top и margin-bottom. С чем это может быть связано?

[image: Скрин]

```
/* -------- CENTER FRAME -------- */
            function updateOL(){

                var sonH = content.outerHeight();
                var finH = $(window).height();

                if (sonH + 60 < finH) {
                    margine = (finH - sonH)/2;
                } else {
                    margine = '30px';
                }
                content.css('margin-top', margine);
                content.css('margin-bottom', margine);
                option.cb_post_resize();
            }
```

Comment: Так посмотрите стили и поправьте их, у вас же даже консоль открыта :-(

Comment: Изменил пост, прикрепил код. Маргины идут из venobox.js, отсюда. С кодом вроде все ок и он должен центрировать открытое изображение, а получается это.

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Закиньте код в сниппет, и вам его поправят